# Linux VIRT memory while running JAR file

Tags: java, linux, memory-leaks

I have a jar which is pretty lightweight, the thing is VIRT memory in linux is increasing and never going back down, I was thinking I had a memory leak but started seeing that the memory increase was happening every time I printed out to console. (Since the app is monitoring it's constantly printing to the console)

Could this be about the console printing? Or I'm missing a leak somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a memory leak, re-creating objects witout destroying. Closed.